# C# ComboBox can't display datasource

Tags: c#, combobox

I try to add a list to a ComboBox as data source when click a button but it doesn't display.
Here is what I tried

```
List<string> data;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data = new List<string>() { "Beginer", "C# Programer", "Object Oriented" };
        comboBox1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

[![Screen Capture: when I click button, data source is updated but it doesn't display][1]][1]

But it works when I add a list

```
List<Food> data;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        data = new List<Food>()
        {
            new Food() {Name = "Hotdog", Price = 10 },
            new Food() {Name = "Paparati", Price = 12 }
        };

        comboBox1.DataSource = data;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
```

Comment: This should work considering the code you showed.. Are you showing other items in your combo box and then on click changing the data source ? The information you provided is not enough to detect the source of the issue.

Comment: Is it a WinForm project?

Comment: It's a winform project. Thank you everyone, now I know why it didn't display datasource: the reason is I set property Combobox.Sorted = true. But I still don't know how Sorted = true make this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this using a `BindingSource`:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = new List<string> { "test1", "test2" };
comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
```

If this is a webform you have to use `Databind`

```
Combobox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: it works when I add datasource as a list of object like : List<Food>. But I cant display with list<string>.

Comment: When debugging what is the value of `combobox1.displaymember` property? Try setting it to `"value"`

Comment: Thank you everyone, now I know why it didn't display datasource: the reason is I set property Combobox.Sorted = true. But I still don't know how Sorted = true make this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


            List<string> data;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            data = new List<string>() { "Beginer", "C# Programer", "Object      ``Oriented" };
            comboBox1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it works when I add datasource as a list of object like : List<Food>. But I cant display with list<string>

Comment: Thank you everyone, now I know why it didn't display datasource: the reason is I set property Combobox.Sorted = true. But I still don't know how Sorted = true make this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind Combobox for winform such as;

```
Combobox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
Combobox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, now I know why it didn't display datasource: the reason is I set property Combobox.Sorted = true. But I still don't know how Sorted = true make this problem.